# System IO File Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to upload image to my web server by using asp.net. My code can upload the image to the directory. I want take the uploaded image and resize it. Unfortunately my code gives Filo not found error here

```
 System.Drawing.Image imgPhoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("../aaa/bbb/ccc.jpg");
```

By the way, it works fine on the visual studio locally.

Here is the upload part.

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../aaa/bbb/ccc.jpg"));
```

Here I try to take the picture and resize it..

```
try
    {
        System.Drawing.Image imgPhoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("../akademi/resimler/4027.jpg");

        //Resizing code
        //Resizing code

        bmPhoto.Save("../aaa/bbb/k_ccc.jpg");
```

The web server is IIS 6

Comment: Use `Server.MapPath` with `FromFile` also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Server.MapPath worked fine. Thank you.